# binary read/write runtime failure

Tags: c++, gcc, file-io, binary, redhat

I've looked at binary reading and writing objects in c++ but are having some problems. It "works" but in addition I get a huge output of errors/"info".

What I've done is

```
Person p2;

std::fstream file;
file.open( filename.c_str(), std::ios::in | std::ios::out | std::ios::binary );
file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg );
file.read ( (char*)&p2, sizeof(p2));
file.close();
std::cout << "Name: " << p2.name;
```

Person is a simple struct containing `string name` and `int age`. When I run the program it outputs "Name: Bob" since I have already made a program to write to a file (so the object is already in filename).

IN ADDITION to outputting the name it also outputs:

*** glibc detected *** program: double free og corruption (fastttop):  ***

Backtrace:

...

Memory map:

...

Abort

Comment: Don't re-type code it can introduce errors. __Cut and Paste__ code. Binary read/write of an object will only work if the structure contains no pointers. This rule must be recursively applied to all members. So if any member or members member or members members member is a pointer this will break. WIthout more information about Person it is hard to tell if that will actually work.

Comment: Show us the declaration of Person.

Comment: Remember that a compiler is allowed to insert padding between fields in structures, classes and unions.  Another issue is that strings usually have to have space allocated for them, read into that space, then assigned to a structure, *unless the text field is a fixed size*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the name string in the Person struct a character array or a STL string? You can't fill in an STL String by binary reading data over top of it, since the data format is not serializable (contains pointers)

Answer (score 1):

It would be interesting to see how you write the information to file as well, as well as how the `Person` struct is built.
If you don't have any problem that the file is plain text, my suggestion would be to write to file using `string::c_str()` (which returns a const char*) as well as using `itoa()` or `itoa_s()` to get the integer as a char*.

You can also have one or several constructors in Person:

```
Person(const std::string& name, int age);  
Person(const char* name, int age);
```

then, when you extract the data from the file you just call the constructor with that data.

Answer (score 0):

Either p2.name is a char* and you are writing and reading the pointer value, not what is pointed by it.  Or p2.name is a more complex type such as std::string which is using internaly pointers with the same problem.

Serializing classes often need more work than just dumping the memory representation.

Answer (score 0):

You said you wrote the Person object to a file. Did you tried to use a dump tool to see if what you have inside the file is what you are expecting?

Also did you tried to instead of using string, use a ordinary char (as @bdk pointed out) ?

Answer (score 0):

When you use binary IO, the size must be fixed. If you use STL string here, it would have a problem as the size of a STL string is arbitrary.